# how can I use babel stand alone in ie11

Tags: javascript, babeljs, internet-explorer-11

I am attempting to use babel stand alone.
everything works fine until ie11. in ie11 I get a blank page and can find no erors.

run snippet below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="templateContainer"></div>

    <script id="template" type="text/x-handlbars-template">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                {{#each panels}}
                <!-- Academic Group -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="{{id}}">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{@index}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>{{title}}</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse{{@index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="{{id}}">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            {{#each this.children}}
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus text-primary"></span>
                                <a href="/sites/csl/SitePages/StaffHelpPages/{{this.aspx}}.aspx" title="{{title}}">{{title}}</a>
                            </li>
                            {{/each}}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015, es2016, es2017, stage-3">
        const data = {
            panels: [
                {
                    title: 'Academic', id: 'headingOne',
                    children: [
                        { title: 'AY20 Academic Calendar', aspx: 'AY_Calendar' },
                        { title: 'Compass', aspx: 'Compass' },
                        { title: 'Gift Funds', aspx: 'Gift_Funds' },
                        { title: 'Manuscript Clearance for Public Release', aspx: 'Manuscript_Clearance_for_Public_Release' },
                        { title: 'Mementos', aspx: 'Mementos' },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'Admin', id: 'headingTwo',
                    children: [
                        { title: 'Alternate_Work_Schedule', aspx: 'Alternate Work Schedule' },
                        { title: 'Civilian Personnel System Access Requests', aspx: 'Civilian_Personnel_System_Access_Requests' },
                        { title: 'Comp Time / Overtime Form', aspx: 'Comp_Time_Form' },
                        { title: 'CSL Leadership Contact Numbers', aspx: 'CSL_Leadership_Contact_Numbers' },
                        { title: 'Federal and Training Holidays', aspx: 'Federal_and_Training_Holidays' },
                        { title: 'Gears', aspx: 'Gears' },
                        { title: 'HHD Leave and Passes', aspx: 'HHD_Leave_and_Passes' },
                        { title: 'Military Leave Requests', aspx: 'Military Leave Requests' },
                        { title: 'NCOER', aspx: 'NCOER' },
                        { title: 'Pentagon', aspx: 'Pentagon' },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }


        const source = $("#template").html();
        const template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        const output = template(data);
        $("#templateContainer").append(output);
    </script>
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Daniel White. run the snippet it is a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: `standalone` is meant for random REPLs and demos, not for any production usecases. If you need to compile an application to function on older environments, you should set up a proper build process to compile your code before it is deployed.

Comment: its an old sharepoint site that allows you to add html / javascript as a web part. we still support ie11 and I wanted to use es6. hence the standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone else hits this problem adding core-js before babel stand alone fixes it in ie11.

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/3.16.0/minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.